# Unable to View Custom Login Page Using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to build a Spring Boot Thymeleaf application to make use of Spring Security. I was trying to get redirected to my custom login page however I am getting the "localhost redirected you too many times." error once I try to do it.

My Config File:

```
package com.emir.securitydemo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class EmployeeSecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new EmployeeUserDetailsService();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                //.requestMatchers("/login/showMyLoginPage").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login/showMyLoginPage").permitAll()
                .and().build();
                
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    
    

}
```

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.emir.securitydemo.service.EmployeeService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
    
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService empService;
    
    @GetMapping("/showMyLoginPage")
    public String welcome() {
        return "login-page";
    }

}
```

Project Structure:
[image: Project Structure]

I am able to get my default view page once I cleared inside of the .loginPage(). I tried various ways of editing my SecurityFilterChain function however I could not figure it out.
[image]

Debug Logs:

```
2023-02-10T18:53:31.648+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2023-02-10T18:53:31.648+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2023-02-10T18:53:31.648+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2023-02-10T18:53:31.649+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@35e7fcf2
2023-02-10T18:53:31.649+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@da4c5cb
2023-02-10T18:53:31.650+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2023-02-10T18:53:31.650+03:00  INFO 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2023-02-10T18:53:31.715+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.729+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.emir.securitydemo.controller.LoginController#welcome()
2023-02-10T18:53:31.748+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.748+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login/login-page', model {}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.751+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [login/login-page]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.758+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2023-02-10T18:53:31.763+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.763+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.emir.securitydemo.controller.LoginController#welcome()
2023-02-10T18:53:31.764+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.764+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login/login-page', model {}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.765+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [login/login-page]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.768+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2023-02-10T18:53:31.773+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.774+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.emir.securitydemo.controller.LoginController#welcome()
2023-02-10T18:53:31.775+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.775+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login/login-page', model {}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.775+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [login/login-page]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.778+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2023-02-10T18:53:31.784+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.785+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.emir.securitydemo.controller.LoginController#welcome()
2023-02-10T18:53:31.786+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.786+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login/login-page', model {}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.786+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [login/login-page]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.790+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2023-02-10T18:53:31.795+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.796+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.emir.securitydemo.controller.LoginController#welcome()
2023-02-10T18:53:31.797+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.797+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login/login-page', model {}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.797+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [login/login-page]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.800+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2023-02-10T18:53:31.806+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.807+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.emir.securitydemo.controller.LoginController#welcome()
2023-02-10T18:53:31.808+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.808+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login/login-page', model {}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.808+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [login/login-page]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.810+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2023-02-10T18:53:31.814+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.815+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.emir.securitydemo.controller.LoginController#welcome()
2023-02-10T18:53:31.816+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.816+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login/login-page', model {}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.816+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [login/login-page]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.818+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2023-02-10T18:53:31.823+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.823+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.emir.securitydemo.controller.LoginController#welcome()
2023-02-10T18:53:31.825+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.825+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login/login-page', model {}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.825+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [login/login-page]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.828+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2023-02-10T18:53:31.833+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.834+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [io-8080-exec-10] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.emir.securitydemo.controller.LoginController#welcome()
2023-02-10T18:53:31.836+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.836+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login/login-page', model {}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.836+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [login/login-page]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.840+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2023-02-10T18:53:31.845+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.845+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.emir.securitydemo.controller.LoginController#welcome()
2023-02-10T18:53:31.846+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.846+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login/login-page', model {}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.846+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [login/login-page]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.848+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2023-02-10T18:53:31.853+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.854+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.emir.securitydemo.controller.LoginController#welcome()
2023-02-10T18:53:31.854+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.854+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login/login-page', model {}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.855+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [login/login-page]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.857+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2023-02-10T18:53:31.862+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.862+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.emir.securitydemo.controller.LoginController#welcome()
2023-02-10T18:53:31.863+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.863+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login/login-page', model {}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.864+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [login/login-page]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.868+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2023-02-10T18:53:31.873+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.874+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.emir.securitydemo.controller.LoginController#welcome()
2023-02-10T18:53:31.875+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.875+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login/login-page', model {}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.875+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [login/login-page]
2023-02-10T18:53:31.877+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2023-02-10T18:53:31.881+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2023-02-10T18:53:31.881+03:00 DEBUG 1984 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to
```

Comment: @dsp_user `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` was deprecated by Spring. See the [link](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)  for further information.

Comment: Also the logs you have posted is only the starting logs of the server. You started the server and then copied the logs. We need the logs from when you are doing what it is you are doing. So that we can read the logs and see what server is doing

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thanks for letting me know. I have updated the logs. As I realize that the program keeps redirecting me to the same page and that's why I get _localhost redirected you too many times._ error. I have uploaded the project to GitHub so you can also check it out from [here](https://github.com/wiitcha/spring-boot-security).

Comment: @witcha, all those redirects (302) in the log clearly point to what is happening but I don't see anything wrong in your code. I can't say if that's a Spring boot bug either. you can perhaps try to use a default login page http.formLogin(withDefaults()); just to see if it makes any difference.